# EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) crash error only for release version

Tags: ios, crash, sigabrt

The app that I have runs perfectly fine in debug mode but when tested in ad hoc in release mode a crash happens. The crash actually happens when the app first starts. I don't really know how to debug or proceed to find out what's the issue. Xcode doesn't throw any error.

The following is my crash log

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2eb6dfce __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3970ecca objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2eaa49c0 -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:] + 420
3   geezer                          0x0008dfce 0x25000 + 430030
4   geezer                          0x0008d2c0 0x25000 + 426688
5   UIKit                           0x3138e4c6 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 514
6   UIKit                           0x3138e284 -[UIViewController view] + 20
7   geezer                          0x000413fa 0x25000 + 115706
8   geezer                          0x00041082 0x25000 + 114818
9   geezer                          0x0005616e 0x25000 + 201070
10  UIKit                           0x313f95a2 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 270
11  UIKit                           0x313f8ef6 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1606
12  UIKit                           0x313f3586 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 710
13  UIKit                           0x3138f704 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3536
14  UIKit                           0x3138e86c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
15  UIKit                           0x313f2cc4 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 612
16  GraphicsServices                0x339c8ae8 _PurpleEventCallback + 604
17  GraphicsServices                0x339c86d2 PurpleEventCallback + 30
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2eb38ab2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2eb38a4e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2eb37222 __CFRunLoopRun + 1394
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2eaa1f0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2eaa1cee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
23  UIKit                           0x313f1eec -[UIApplication _run] + 756
24  UIKit                           0x313ed168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
25  geezer                          0x0008b19a 0x25000 + 418202
26  libdyld.dylib                   0x39c1bab2 tlv_initializer + 2


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39cd11f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d3b792 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39c81fd8 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38fb0cd2 abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38fc96e0 default_terminate_handler() + 248
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3970ef62 _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38fc71c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38fc6d28 __cxa_rethrow + 96
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3970ee12 objc_exception_rethrow + 38
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2eaa1f80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 636
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2eaa1cee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
11  UIKit                           0x313f1eec -[UIApplication _run] + 756
12  UIKit                           0x313ed168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
13  geezer                          0x0008b19a 0x25000 + 418202
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x39c1bab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39cbe808 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x39c00078 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x39bffdfe _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39cd1c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d38bda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d38a94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39cd1c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d38bda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d38a94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  AFNetworking
Thread 4:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3971794c objc_opt::objc_selopt_t::get(char const*) const + 36
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39717828 __sel_registerName(char const*, int, int) + 40
2   CFNetwork                       0x2e7fec56 ___ZN24ClassicConnectionSession14processDefaultEv_block_invoke + 34
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x39bf681c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x39bfe60a dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 42
5   CFNetwork                       0x2e7fec2e ClassicConnectionSession::processDefault() + 38
6   CFNetwork                       0x2e7a9e90 URLProtocol::getProtocolRegistry() + 4
7   CFNetwork                       0x2e761d28 _CFURLProtocolRegisterFoundationBridge + 8
8   Foundation                      0x2f4dfb94 +[_NSCFURLProtocolBridge registerWithCFURLProtocol] + 168
9   Foundation                      0x2f4dfa9c NSURLProtocolInit + 316
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d3b82c __pthread_once_handler + 48
11  libsystem_platform.dylib        0x39d334e0 _os_once + 40
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d39ada pthread_once + 46
13  Foundation                      0x2f4aca0c +[NSURLProtocol(NSURLProtocolPrivate) _registeredClasses] + 48
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x39bf681c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x39bfe60a dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 42
16  Foundation                      0x2f4abccc -[NSURLConnection(Private) _initWithRequest:delegate:usesCache:maxContentLength:startImmediately:connectionProperties:] + 464
17  Foundation                      0x2f4fdd0a -[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:] + 50
18  geezer                          0x0003153a 0x25000 + 50490
19  Foundation                      0x2f556c6e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 382
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2eb39258 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2eb38726 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2eb36f1a __CFRunLoopRun + 618
23  CoreFoundation                  0x2eaa1f0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
24  CoreFoundation                  0x2eaa1cee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
25  Foundation                      0x2f4941e6 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
26  Foundation                      0x2f4e509c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
27  geezer                          0x0002fd12 0x25000 + 44306
28  Foundation                      0x2f556a5a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d3a916 _pthread_body + 138
30  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d3a886 _pthread_start + 98
31  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d38aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39cbea58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39cbe854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2eb38896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2eb36fbc __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2eaa1f0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2eaa1cee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2f4e1082 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 314
7   Foundation                      0x2f556a5a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d3a916 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d3a886 _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d38aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3bcb518c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x27dde584
    r8: 0x17d745a0    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x000e6070     r11: 0x000e3994
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27dde578      lr: 0x39d3b797      pc: 0x39cd11f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Update: After reading tonnes of stuff on the internet about symbolicating, finally I managed to do it with Xcode 5. Some were pretty complicated with the need to use the terminal. Luckily all I needed to do was to go to Organizer in Xcode, grab the latest Archive in Finder. Show Package Contents from that file to get the dsym folder. Copy it out to a folder together with the ipa file and then just install the ipa through Organizer. The crash log will look much more meaningful.

Comment: Symbolicate the crash log.

Comment: Given the log, you are passing a bad index to `NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:`. Symbolicating the log will tell you where in your app this is happening.

Comment: thanks rmaddy for the tip. It helped me in solving the issue.

Comment: @ken - this question is sort of in limbo. It doesn't have a useful answer and might be better deleted. If you want you could answer your own question, which might give it more value, or simply delete it if the answer is mundane. BTW - Plugging the device into your Mac and then opening the Organizer window will show a pretty version of the log (just click the device logs for the device and select the latest crash - assumes the device is available or you can replicate the issue on a local device).

Answer (score 0):

After reading tonnes of stuff on the internet about symbolicating, finally I managed to do it with Xcode 5. Some were pretty complicated with the need to use the terminal. Luckily all I needed to do was to go to Organizer in Xcode, grab the latest Archive in Finder. Show Package Contents from that file to get the dsym folder. Copy it out to a folder together with the ipa file and then just install the ipa through Organizer. The crash log will look much more meaningful.